# Obtain file access permissions on read-only-mounted volume? (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7

I made an image of my entire C:\ drive using EaseUS Todo Backup Free, before formatting and setting up a new Windows (7 Professional) system. I can mount that image read-only in Todo Backup and copy over a few files which I need, everything fine up to here.

Problem is, I need to access some of the files in C:\Users\dvrcoder files on that image. I can't access them since they are owned by the "old" dvrcoder user (whose SID was different than the new one on the new Windows system). I also can't obtain ownership of the files, because the mounted backup image is read-only.

Can I somehow "connect" to the drive using a different SID? Or mount it in a different way? Or make a new user with a SID corresponding to the old one? Or access the files in some other way?

Comment: Have you tried taking ownership of the folder using the security tab of properties of that folder>

Answer (score 3):

You can copy the folder in question to your local disk using robocopy.

Start an administrative command line window by typing `cmd` into the Start Menu and pressing Control-Shift-ENTER.

Assuming the volume is mounted as drive E, and that you are running as administrator, type the following command:

```
robocopy /e /b e:\users\dvrcoder c:\copy-of-dvrcoder
```

The /b option tells robocopy to use backup privilege to override the security permissions.

Comment: Brilliant; this approach does work! I did, however, need to add the switches to ignore errors in Robocopy, `/R:0 /W:0`, as I received countless `the name of the file cannot be resolved by the system` errors accompanied by a 30-second timeout in each instance, presumably due to path lengths in excess of what Windows allows.

Comment: @Ben, robocopy bypasses the usual path name length limitation, but there may have been symbolic links that couldn't be resolved.  That sort of issue is pretty much normal when dealing with images of system drives.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [taking ownership of the folder](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753659.aspx) using the security tab in properties of that folder?

> Easeus Note: We suggest you [mount the image file with the same Windows user](http://www.todo-backup.com/support/help/mount.htm) which you used to create the image file. This can ensure you have full access permission after the driver mounted.

Comment: @Easeus Note: That's exactly what I'm trying to do, problem is, said user doesn't exist anymore because my new Windows system has different SIDs from the old system... Can I make a Windows user with a custom SID for that purpose?

Comment: @taking ownership: doesn't work, whether I open Explorer as Admin or not. My interpretation was that I couldn't write new permissions to the file because the image is read-only.

Comment: Ok, installed Easeus, did not see any option to mount images with write permissions, evidently free version has limitations.

Comment: I have the paid version and it does not appear to provide an option for mounting with read-write access, either. Fortunately, the Robocopy method described in https://superuser.com/a/429534/176764 does allow me to copy the files to another location to which I have access.